# TIdTCPClient Write Bytes

Tags: delphi

```pascal
  if _msg.isRequest then
  begin
    req:= THTTPRequest(_msg);
    msgBody:= req.getMessageBody;

    // Adds the URI line.
    str:= str + req.getMethod + ' ';
    str:= str + req.getURI + ' ';
    str:= str + versionText + CRLF;

    // Sets the content length header if its a POST
    if req.getMethod = 'POST' then
      req.setHeader(THTTPHeaderKey.CONTENT_LENGTH.ToString, IntToStr(Length(msgBody) * SizeOf(Char)));

    // Adds the headers
    for i:= 0 to req.getHeaders.Count -1  do
      str:= str + req.getHeaders.Names[i] + '=' + req.getHeaders.ValueFromIndex[i];
    str:= str + CRLF;

    // Adds the message body if its POST
    if req.getMethod = 'POST' then
      str:= str + msgBody;

    // Writes the result to the output stream.
    formPopupRemote.IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.Write(Byte(str)); -> ERROR LINE
//    formPopupRemote.HTTP.Get(str, stream);
  end
  else
    ShowMessage('Responses sending not yet supported!');
end;
```

I want to writes the result to the IOHandler. But how can i do this, i converted this code from JAVA.

Here is Java Codes :

```java
if (_msg.isRequest()) {
        HTTPRequest req = (HTTPRequest) _msg;
        String msgBody = req.getMessageBody();

        // Adds the URI line.
        str.append(req.getMethod() + " ");
        str.append(req.getURI() + " ");
        str.append(versionText + CRLF);

        // Sets the content length header if its a POST
        if (req.getMethod() == HTTPRequest.Method.POST)
            req.setHeader(HTTPHeaderKey.CONTENT_LENGTH.toString(), String.valueOf(msgBody.getBytes().length));

        // Adds the headers
        for (String key : req.getHeaders())
            str.append(key + ": " + req.getHeader(key) + CRLF);
        str.append(CRLF);

        // Adds the message body if its POST
        if (req.getMethod() == HTTPRequest.Method.POST)
            str.append(msgBody);

        // Writes the result to the output stream.
        getOutputStream().write(str.toString().getBytes());

    } else {
        throw new ProtocolException("Responses sending not yet supported!");
    }
}
```

Actually i want to convert to Delphi from Java codes. But i couldn' t find outputstream equals in Delphi. Because TIdClient.IOHandler.Write has no `TBytes` parameter or `array of Byte`. But outputstream' s parameter is `array of byte`. So how should i write `str`?

Comment: Use the `TIdHttp`client instead of TIdTCPclient, it has support for POST requests...

Comment: could you give me  a sample ?

Comment: What happened to your yesterday question regarding IOHandler.ReadStream(). I would have been interested in knowing what coused your problem.

Comment: @infoihaleden: if you provide examples of actual HTTP requests you want to send, someone can show you how to send them using `TIdHTTP` instead of `TIdTCPClient`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TIdIOHandler` has a `Write()` overload that accepts a `String` as input, so you don't need to manually convert to bytes at all:

```
formPopupRemote.IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.Write(str);
```

But if you did, Indy has overloaded `ToBytes()` functions for that purpose, and one of them accepts a `String` as input:

```
formPopupRemote.IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.Write(ToBytes(str));
```

However, this is overkill, since this is essentially what `TIdIOHandelr.Write(String)` does internally for you.

That being said, you really should be using the `TIdHTTP` component instead of manually formatting an HTTP request and using `TIdTCPClient` to send it.  `TIdHTTP` has `Get()` and `Post()` methods (amongst others).  All you have to do is pass in the full URL, and in the case of `Post()` also pass in a `TStream` object containing the raw body data. `TIdHTTP` also has properties for customing the request so you can set things like HTTP version (`TIdHTTP.ProtocolVersion`), body Content Type (`TIdHTTP.Request.ContentType`) and charset (`TIdHTTP.Request.Charset`), custom request headers (`TIdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders`), etc.  `TIdHTTP` will handle the `Content-Length` header for you automatically.

Comment: You are not supposed to call `ReadLn()` directly when using `TIdHTTP`.  It handles all of the necessary reading internally for you.  All you have to do is call `TIdHTTP.Get()` or `TIdHTTP.Post()` (or any of the many other request methods), and it returns the response content to you as either a `String` or `TStream`, depending on which overload you call.